# Python: Can I replace an object in a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I’m using the pi3d lib in Python on a raspberry pi. What I’m trying to do is dynamically create screen objects, and replace them.
First I want to fill an array of dictionaries. These can be integers, strings or pi3D sprite objects.
I have the following test code:

```
import pi3d

DISPLAY = pi3d.Display.create(x=0, y=0)
shader = pi3d.Shader("uv_flat")
CAMERA = pi3d.Camera(is_3d=False)

screen_items=[]

for item_number in range (5):
    screen_item={}
    screen_item['type']= 'second_rotation_stepped'
    screen_item['text_type']='static'
    screen_item['visible']='always'
    screen_item['image_sprite']=pi3d.ImageSprite(pi3d.Texture("textures/PATRN.PNG", blend=True), shader, w=100.0, h=100.0, z=5.0 ,x=0,y=120*item_number)
    screen_items.append(screen_item)

screen_items[0]['image_sprite']=pi3d.ImageSprite(pi3d.Texture("textures/altimeter.png", blend=True), shader, w=50.0, h=50.0, z=5.0 ,x=0,y=-200)
screen_items[0]['visible']='never'
screen_items[2]['image_sprite'].rotateToZ(45)

mykeys = pi3d.Keyboard()



while DISPLAY.loop_running():
    for drawitem in screen_items:
        drawitem['image_sprite'].draw()

    if mykeys.read() == 27:
        mykeys.close()
        DISPLAY.destroy()
        Break
```

Everything works as I expected but it gives me an error/warning:
“couldn't set to delete”

This error won’t come up if I block out the code:

```
screen_items[0]['image_sprite']=pi3d.ImageSprite(pi3d.Texture("textures/altimeter.png", blend=True), shader, w=50.0, h=50.0, z=5.0 ,x=0,y=-200)
```

I don’t get this error with the code:

```
screen_items[0]['visible']='never'
```

So I guess I can replace a string in a dictionary, but cannot replace an object?
Like I said, everything works fine, the object does get replaced (and drawn on the screen) but somehow the “old”  object isn’t deleted. Is it some kind of pointer problem?

Comment: You can start by assigning the new value to a variable on one line and then assigning the variable to the dictionary on the next line. See where the exception happens (almost certainly on calling `ImageSprite`). Strings are objects (as everything is) in Python, so what you're suggesting can't be true. Also, please copy and paste the exception message exactly.

Comment: Hi Joe, "couldn't set to delete" is the exact message the console window spits out. Just tried to set the new value to new variable and assigning that to the dictionary. Same error message. The program does not crash, I think it's just a warning message.

Comment: No stack trace? Anyway, ojii's answer is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "error" you're seeing is actually a debug message by pi3d when trying to delete the initial `Texture` object created in the for loop in your script.

When you re-assign the new `ImageSprite` object to `screen_items[0]['image_sprite']`, the old `Texture` object gets garbage collected, invoking it's `__del__` method, causing this debug message.

Reference: https://github.com/tipam/pi3d/blob/master/pi3d/Texture.py#L87

Comment: Hi Ojii,

Thanks for looking into it. So, as I understand, pi3D tries to set the unused texture “free” so the python engine sets the allocated memory free with his garbage collection algorithm. But, according to the debug message, this does not work and the allocated memory wont set free? Do I have a memory leak, or is everything fine?

(I’m new to python and this garbage collector feature and I’m really trying to understand what’s going on.)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not familiar with pi3D. Having a quick glance at the code shows me that they use a very broad ``try: ... except: ...`` and do not distinguish between what kind of errors could occur, so it's really hard to say what actually happens and whether this is a memory leak (the *Python* object gets deleted, but maybe pi3D does some more magic). I suggest you try contacting pi3D developers if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

This problem originates because the python garbage collector doesn't tidy up the gpu memory allocated when the Texture instance is created.

In python it is possible to use a `__del__()` method as a destructor but it doesn't necessarily get executed immediately.  When the gpu buffer memory leak was first observed it was confounded by [a bug in the video core due to implementation of EGL](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/185) so pi3d ended up with a 'belt and braces' system whereby references were kept in the Display object to all texture, vertex and element buffers and if, at close down, any of these had not been released by the python objects' `__del__()` methods, there was a final clear out.

However under certain circumstances, very occasionally, when the program was shutting down, the references pointed to objects that had been released before they could remove the references to themselves. As the bug had no impact on running code and would be messy to sort out it had been put on a back-burner.

PS see the raspberry pi forum thread t=79383 for my solutions to @satoer's problems generally